# Disabled button issue in selenium test

Tags: selenium

In my application when page loads "SAVE" button appears in disabled mode and later after entering name it gets enabled, it is happening while recording but while playback with selenium, button is not getting enabled. so not able to save data. What should i do to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of type command in the fields use typeKeys command.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the javascript on the page to see how the button is enabled upon typing. It's most likely through an event listener on a keyUp event or something similar on the given field. In that case, you can either use typeKeys instead of type or you can fire the relevant event when you finished typing using fireEvent method.

Comment: Not working for me, If possible can explain with example. My application has two textboxes with save button and I am using selenium RC to run script.